# Java element filter does not work in eclipse helios (3.6) sr1

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have added the Java element filter in my plugin to hide an xml file from the project explorer view.

but this filter does not seems to be working with the eclipse helios 3.6 sr1 version.

Note that i am using eclipse helios 3.6 sdk version.
Here is the extension point declaration in plugin.xml....

Answer (score 0):

Java Element Filters will work on the Package Explorer view, not the Project Explorer view.